# Az acr build command info needed

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-registry, acr

As per the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli the below command builds and pushes to registry. What if I need only build and then push based on my interest .Because I have to scan image before pushing it.

az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1
--registry myContainerRegistry008
--file Dockerfile .

Note: There is no docker daemon installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_build) ,You can use `--no-push` flag in the `az acr build` command to build the docker file & not to push it to the registry,

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

Comment: I have used this command. It doesn't save the image locally . It just builds and leaves it.